# JAX- WS Complex Objects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cxf, jax-ws

I'm trying out the JAX-WS sample at [sortedset.com](http://blog.sortedset.com/step-by-step-web-services-with-tomcat-tomee-apache-cxf-eclipse/) (Apache CXF, TomEE) and I modified it to include a complex object. I'm getting a `NullPointerException` at `org.apache.cxf.jaxb.Utils.getMethodXJTA(Utils.java:294)`. Is there any missing annotation in my code? Or is there more to be done to marshal complex objects?

```
 import javax.jws.WebService; 

    @WebService(
            portName = "HelloTomEEPort",
            serviceName = "HelloTomEEService",
            targetNamespace = "http://sortedset.com/wsdl",
            endpointInterface = "HelloTomEEWs")
    public class HelloTomEEIMplementation implements HelloTomEEWs {

       public Person getPerson(){
            Person p =  new Person();
            p.setID(5);
            p.setName("Tom");
            return p;
        }

    }
```

---

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://sortedset.com/wsdl")
public interface HelloTomEEWs {
    @WebMethod    
    public Person getPerson();


}
```

---

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;

@XmlRegistry
public class Person{
 /**
     * 
     */
private int iD;
 private String name;
public int getID() {
    return iD;
}
public void setID(int iD) {
    this.iD = iD;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

> SEVERE: Error deploying CXF webservice for servlet
>   HelloTomEEIMplementation java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.Utils.getMethodXJTA(Utils.java:294)   at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(JAXBContextInitializer.java:375)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(JAXBContextInitializer.java:329)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addType(JAXBContextInitializer.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(JAXBContextInitializer.java:365)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(JAXBContextInitializer.java:329)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.begin(JAXBContextInitializer.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.ServiceModelVisitor.visitOperation(ServiceModelVisitor.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.ServiceModelVisitor.walk(ServiceModelVisitor.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:325)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:490)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:697)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:550)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:214)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfEndpoint.doServiceCreate(CxfEndpoint.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.pojo.PojoEndpoint.(PojoEndpoint.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.pojo.PojoWsContainer.createEndpoint(PojoWsContainer.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.pojo.PojoWsContainer.createEndpoint(PojoWsContainer.java:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfWsContainer.start(CxfWsContainer.java:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfService.createPojoWsContainer(CxfService.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.webservices.WsService.afterApplicationCreated(WsService.java:390)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.webservices.TomeeJaxWsService.afterApplicationCreated(TomeeJaxWsService.java:54)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager$Observer.invoke(ObserverManager.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager.fireEvent(ObserverManager.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.loader.SystemInstance.fireEvent(SystemInstance.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.afterStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1608)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Post your full stacktrace here

Comment: @colossus Posted the trace

Comment: Looks like a bug in CXF. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest TomEE 1.6.0.2 / CXF 2.6.14

Answer (score 0):

try to use `@XmlType` instead of `@XmlRegistry`